# Jupyter notebook cannot be open in a browser after I installed an new environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was using tensorflow-gpu=1.14, I had to update it to newer version.
So I uninstalled it and remove the `conda` environment and recreated a new `conda` environment.

The python version now is 3.7.
I am using a server with Centos system.

I used to open the jupyter notebook by `jupyter-notebook --ip=192.168.1.200 --no-browser --port=9999` then copy the URL to my browser.
[image]
It appears to work too, but the URL is not working. `The site cannot be reached`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the choice of port. I have no idea why 6666 did not work.

I tried 8888 and 9999, both of them worked.

Comment: 8888,9999 At least these two worked, so I stopped trying.

Comment: It would be great if you could edit that information into your answer... Also please try finding *why* 6666 didn't work... That might be very useful to future readers..